# Translation of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

I am given a complex polynomial $p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + \cdots + a_nz^n$, with $a_j \in \Bbb C$ for all $j$. Then, we fix $z_0 \in \Bbb C$ and define $P(z) = p(z+z_0)$, and I must prove that $P$ is also a polynomial. By doing some examples, comparing with the Pascal triangle, doing case $n = 4$, looking for patterns and such, I can conjecture that: $$P(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^nb_kz^k, \quad \text{where} \quad b_k = \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} {k+j \choose j}a_{k+j}z_0^{j}.$$

But I'm having trouble proving this. If I go for straight for the definition: $$\begin{align} P(z)=p(z+z_0) &= \sum_{k=0}^na_k(z+z_0)^k \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^n a_k\sum_{j=0}^k{k \choose j}z_0^{k-j}z^j  \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\sum_{j=0}^k{k \choose j}a_kz_0^{k-j}z^j\right),\end{align}$$ and I'm stuck. I think that there must be some clever  relabeling of indices here, but I can't see it. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

(I should also add that the approach to this problem is preferred to be elementary. I have thought in the lines of Taylor expanding $p$ in some way, but we should not kill an ant with a cannon.)

Comment: Have you tried switching the exponents of $z_0$ and $z$ when using the binomial theorem? And then commuting the summations?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help much. And I don't think I can commute the summations here, because the limits of one summation are in the other one.. $$\sum_{\color{red}{k}=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^{\color{red}{k}}$$

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right, sorry. Would induction on the degree of the polynomial be considered elementary? I tried it out on paper and it seems to work. Or would you rather have something relying purely on algebraic manipulations? Also, I think the exponent of $z_0$ in your sum should be $k-j$ rather than $n-j$

Comment: In the second line of your last sequence of formulas, I believe that the exponent of $z_0$ is incorrect - it should be $k-j$ instead of $n-j$ since you are expanding $(z+z_0)^k$ with the inner sum (oops, Reveillark was faster than me, bummer)

Comment: You're right guys, that's what I meant. Fixed, thanks for pointing.

Comment: The second line is still wrong... :-P

Comment: @Reveillark Induction is okay, I'll also try it.

Comment: @Pedro you're fast haha. All ok now?

Comment: Yep, you can sleep sound now ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group terms by powers of $z$ as
\begin{align*}
P(z) &= \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \sum_{j=0}^{k} {k \choose j} a_k z_0^{n-j} z^j \right)\\
&= \left( {0 \choose 0} a_0 z_0^{n-0} + {1 \choose 0} a_1 z_0^{n-1} + \ldots + {n \choose 0} a_n z_0^{n-n} \right) z^0 \\
&\hspace{10mm} + \left( {1 \choose 1} a_1 z_0^{n-1} + \ldots + {n \choose 1} a_n z_0^{n-n} \right) z^1 + \ldots \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \sum_{j=k}^n {j \choose k} a_j z_0^{n-(n-(j-k))} \right) z^k
\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} {i + k \choose k} a_{i+k} z_0^{i} \right) z^k,
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows by making the substitution $i = j-k$.

Comment: Just to be sure, is there a way of making the step without expanding everything to see that? I think it makes the calculation lose a bit of the formality, but then, I'm just being a prick here. Glad that my conjecture was right. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The step where I expanded things was indeed a little gross, but the idea I was trying to convey was just to group everything possible by the powers of $z$ that were available, and then rewrite all these things somehow as a sum (and I think my indices worked out, but if there are any little errors, commenters please let me know!).

Comment: I just found a way to "skip" that step. We actually have $$\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^k = \sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=j}^n.$$
It works like a sort of a variable change in double integrals.. If we draw a grid it is easier to convince yourself of this. (Just giving this extra feedback because I thought you would like to know this)

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach:

Let $e_k(z) = z^k$, $f_k(z) = (z+z_0)^k$, and show that with
$E_n = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_k \}_{k=0}^n$, $ F_n = \operatorname{sp} \{ f_k \}_{k=0}^n$ we have $E_n = F_n$.

It is clear that $E_0 = F_0$. Suppose $E_n = F_n$. We have
$f_{n+1}(z) = z (z+z_0)^n + z_0 (z+z_0)^n = z f_n(z)+ z_0 f_n(z)$, and since
$f_n \in E_n$, we have $f_{n+1} \in E_{n+1}$. It follows that $F_{n+1} \subset E_{n+1}$.

Similarly, 
$e_{n+1}(z) = (z+z_0)z^n - z_0 z^n = (z+z_0)e_n(z) - z_0 e_n(z)$, and
since $e_n \in F_n$ we have $e_{n+1} \in F_{n+1}$. It follows that $E_{n+1} \subset F_{n+1}$.

**Addendum**: Actually, the above can be shortened using the binomial theorem.

Since $f_k = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} z_0^{k-i} e_i$, we have $f_k \in E_n$ for all $k \le n$ and so $F_n \subset E_n$.

Since $e_k = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} (-z_0)^{k-i} f_i$, we have $e_k \in F_n$ for all $k \le n$ and so $E_n \subset F_n$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a way to do it by induction. First, I'll modify your notation slightly to make it more induction-hypothesis-friendly: $b_k^{(n)} = \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{n-k}{k+j \choose k}a_{k+j}z_0^j$

I'll limit myself to the inductive step, $p$ is now a polynomial of degree $n+1$.

$$P(Z)=a_{n+1}(z+z_0)^{n+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(z+z_0)^k=a_{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n+1 \choose k}z_0 ^{n+1-k}z^k+\sum_{k=0}^{n}b_k ^{(n)} z^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n}z^k\left ( a_{n+1}{n+1 \choose k}z_0 ^{n+1-k} + b_k ^{(n)} \right ) +a_{n+1}z^{n+1}$$

Now note that, by definition $a_{n+1}=b_{n+1} ^{(n+1)}$

Also: $a_{n+1}{n+1 \choose k}z_0 ^{n+1-k} + b_k ^{(n)}=a_{n+1}{n+1 \choose k}z_0 ^{n+1-k} + \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{n-k}{k+j \choose j}a_{k+j}z_0 ^j=a_{k+((n+1)-k)}{k+((n+1)-k) \choose k}z_0 ^{n+1-k}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}{k+j \choose j}a_{k+j}z_0 ^j=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1-k}{k+j \choose j}a_{k+j}z_0 ^j = b_{k}^{(n+1)}$

Comment: I thought it would be uglier. Thank you! +1

Comment: (By the way, it would be $a_{n+1} = b_{n+1}^{(n+1)}$ only, and there is a $k+k$ typo in the beginning)